# HTML CSS Search box with 2 input

Tags: html, css, search

I need to create a search box with two text inputs. The search should be specific to name and place. Does anyone have a suggestion?

I have this code but it has only one text input. I need an input that looks good.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @JohnArzaga - indent 4 spaces to show code or click the `<>` like I did and added the CSS needed for a [mcve] - NEVER post code in comments - they do not format well. Just update the question

Comment: Yeah I guess I already have there in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```css
.form-control { width:45% !important; }
#srch-term1 { margin-right:5px }
.btn { margin-left:-35px !important; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="srch-term" id="srch-term1" type="text">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Place" name="srch-term" id="srch-term2" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanx, i'll just find some tricks to make it beautiful. Just like ramukaka.com

Answer (score 0):

two field of search box

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search1" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search2" name="srch-term2" id="srch-term2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```